# How to remove all names from the array list before a certain string?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

In an array list, if you add a string, then sort it, then want to delete everything before that string, what would you do?

Comment: If strings are unique you can use a `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 4):

Get the index of the newly added element.  Use this index to get a sublist and pass the sublist to the `removeAll` method:

**Removing**

```
//addition = newly added String     
list.removeAll(new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(0,list.indexOf(addition))));
```

**Full Example**

```
public class ArrayListSortDelete {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String addition = "BB";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }));
        list.add(addition);
        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("Before");
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

            //new ArrayList<String>() avoids concurrent modification.
        list.removeAll(new ArrayList<String>(list.subList(0,list.indexOf(addition))));

        System.out.println("After:");
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Might be better to use `Collections.binarySearch`  rather than `indexOf` as the `List` is sorted and this would be **much** faster for large lists.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for suggesting the binary search, I will investigate this evening.

Answer (score 3):

This should be alright

```
ArrayList<String> yourList;
String query;    

int index = yourList.indexOf(query);
for (int a=0; a<index; a++) {
    yourList.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list and keep removing the elements till you find that String.

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
  if (!(list.get(i).equal("String"))) {
    list.remove(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This falls into the classic string comparison bug. Compare strings with `equals` and not `==`.

Comment: Would be acceptable if it was typo-free and was actually the best solution (using `equals(Object)` instead of `==` for `String` comparison) From the looks of it, you do have the right idea. Just fix the errors.

Comment: You have errors: You used class name instead of object name. You use wrong way to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) and [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29).

Consider reading the linked documentation for more information.

**Code example:**

```
list.subList(0, list.indexOf(searched_string)).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Kevin Bowersox have given an answer, I am here to give you an alternative  :)

Another way to interpret your problem is:

Given an array list, and a new element, remove all elements in the array list that is less than the new element, then put the new element in the list and sort the list.

Here is one way:

```
ArrayList<String> oList = .....;
List<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>(); // tmp list to store the result
String newElement = ...;

for (String s: oList) {
    if (s.compareTo(newElement) >= 0) { //  s >= newElement
        newList.add(s);
    }
}
newList.add(newElement);

// put the result back to oList
oList.clear();
oList.putAll(newList);

// sort the result
Collections.sort(oList);

// now oList contains what you want
```

You may even do it in-place in the oList without help of a temp list (but remove of arrayList is not efficient).